# Take first 4 values in input parameter using oracle 10g

Tags: oracle

I am using Oracle-10g, im creating one query that needs to take first 4 values in input parameter.

user will give many inputs while run the report in module, but query needs to take first 4 values if user gives more than 4.
Take all the values if user gives less than 4 or equal to 4.
Every input value will be seperated by comma(,) by the user.
user's input value is the parameter in the qry.

My qry as follows:

```
SELECT C.COUNTRY_NAME,OA.CITY,OA.COUNTRY_CODE,D.DEPARTURE_NO,O.STORER_ORDER_ID
FROM
ORDERS O,
ORDER_ADDRESS OA,
STORE_ADRESS SA,
DEPARTURE D,
SHIPMENT S,
LUID L,
PICKLIST_LINE_PACK_LUID PL,
STORER ST,COUNTRY C
WHERE O.INTERNAL_ORDER_ID=OA.INTERNAL_ORDER_ID
AND O.SHIPMENT_ID=S.SHIPMENT_ID
AND S.DEPARTURE_NO=D.DEPARTURE_NO
AND PL.INTERNAL_ORDER_ID=O.INTERNAL_ORDER_ID
AND PL.PACK_LUID_NO=L.LUID_NO
AND O.STORER_ID=ST.STORER_ID
AND ST.STORE_ID=SA.STORE_ID
and C.COUNTRY_CODE=OA.COUNTRY_CODE
and D.DEPARTURE_NO IN(
CASE WHEN length('9821,9254,225,9821') - nvl(length(replace('9821,9254,225,9821',',')),0) <=3
THEN
9821,9254,225,9821
End
)
```

this gives me an error as "ORA-00905: missing keyword"

Can anyone plss help me out on this ???

Thanks in advance,
Priya

Answer (score 0):

```
and D.DEPARTURE_NO IN(
CASE WHEN length('9821,9254,225,9821') - nvl(length(replace('9821,9254,225,9821',',')),0) <=3
THEN
9821,9254,225,9821
End
)
```

This condition is incorrect - CASE should return an expression, not a list of expressions.

You can try something like this:

```
and ',' || 
    CASE WHEN LENGTH('9821,9254,225,9821,5') - LENGTH(REPLACE('9821,9254,225,9821,5',',')) > 3
         THEN substr('9821,9254,225,9821,5', 1, instr('9821,9254,225,9821,5', ',', 1, 4)-1)
         ELSE '9821,9254,225,9821,5'
    END  || ','  like '%,' || D.DEPARTURE_NO || ',%'
```

Comment: Thank u so much.. im getting an answer but partially.. this condition works perfectly if i have only 4 inputs.. if inputs exceeds more than 4 ,it dint gives me an answer. My need is, if input exceeds more than 4 it should take first 4 values only. My tried qry:                                                         CASE WHEN length('9908,9896,9891,9875,9869')-nvl(length(replace('9908,9896,9891,9875,9869',',')),0) <=3
THEN ',' || '9908,9896,9891,9875,9869' || ',' END 
like '%,' || D.DEPARTURE_NO || ',%'

Comment: above tried qry doesnt give an answer to me.. but i need to display datas for first 4 values

Comment: Thanks a lot @Multisync.... i got wat i expected accurately.. for past 3 days i was struggling with this concept.. u made my day :)

Comment: Everything is fine but another doubt.. u were counting the digits in INSTR function i think.. but actually inputs are not always a 4 digit number, sometimes might be 3 digit,sometimes might be 5 digits.. (Eg:'9821,925,22525,9821,555852') . wat can i do in this situation ??